# PIC16F1937 and UART : keep led ON while receiving

Tags: c, pic, uart

I'm trying to keep a led ON while PIC is receiving a character (while a button is pressed), the led being OFF by default, but I can't seem to find a solution.

I'm 3 months in learning using microcontrollers (specifically PIC) coding with MPLABX IDE and started understanding UART communication. At first I tried turning a led ON/OFF when a charater is received, it went pretty good and worked, but right now I'm trying to keep a led active while a button is pressed but can't really get over this problem. I have my code in a interrupt function like this :

```
//#define LED RB5

void __interrupt () ISR (void)
{   
    if(RCIF) // data is received
    {
        data = RCREG; // get the value
        if (data == '1') // if value received is '1'
            LED = 1; //turn ON led
        RCIF = 0;
    }
    LED = 0; // turn OFF led
}
```

Using the above code makes so the led turns on/off really fast while I keep pressing a button and isn't really what I wanted.
I hope someone can help me understand what I need to do. Thanks !

Comment: As short session of "Rubber duck debugging" should lead you to the cause of your problem.

Comment: You need to add an `else`.

Comment: According to the datasheet I'm looking at, `RCIF` bit is read only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you create a state machine for this in app.c.

Define some states with an `enum` and a `struct` to hold the state and place them in app.h, include `app.h` in files where you wish to use this module (e.g. your system_interrupt.c file).

For example you could do this:

```
typedef enum{
    IDLE,
    START_RECEIVING,
    STILL_RECEIVING,
}uart_state_t;

typedef struct{
    uart_state_t current_state;
}uart_module_t

volatile uart_module_t uart_module = {0}; // initial state = IDLE, needs to be volatile because it will be updated via interrupt
```

Then create a function to service your state machine. This will handle the state that it is currently in and transition to other states as desired. For instance, the state machine starts in the `IDLE` state but once your interrupt has fired and `RCIF` bit is set then you'll transition in to the `START_RECEIVING` state which will turn the LED on then transition to the `STILL_RECEIVING` state where it will poll the `RCIF` bit until cleared. That would look something like this:

```
void uartFSM(void){

    switch(uart_module.current_state){

        case IDLE:
        {

            break;

        }

        case START_RECEIVING:
        {

            LED = 1; // Turn LED on
            uart_module.current_state = STILL_RECEIVING; // state update

            break;

        }
        case STILL_RECEIVING:
        {

            if(!RCIF){

                // done receiving
                LED = 0; // Turn LED off
                uart_module.current_state = IDLE; // state update

            }

            break;

        }

        default:
        {
            // whoops
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Now your interrupt will look like this:

```
void __interrupt () ISR (void)
{   
    if(RCIF) // data is received
    {

        data = RCREG; // get the value

        // if value received is '1'
        if (data == '1') uart_module.current_state = START_RECEIVING; // state update

    }

}
```

Now you just have to make sure that you call the `uartFSM()` some where in `APP_Tasks` so that the state machine gets serviced.

Answer (score 1):

The LED goes off quickly because you switch if off immediately after switching it on:

```
void __interrupt () ISR (void)
{   
    if(RCIF) // data is received
    {
        data = RCREG; // get the value
        if (data == '1') // if value received is '1'
            LED = 1; //turn ON led
        RCIF = 0;
    }
    LED = 0; // turn OFF led   <<=== This is executed unconditionally.
}
```

You might put `LED = 0;` in an `else` branch if you don't want it to be executed everytime.

Maybe like this:

```
void __interrupt () ISR (void)
{   
    if(RCIF) // data is received
    {
        data = RCREG; // get the value
        if (data == '1') // if value received is '1'
            LED = 1; //turn ON led
        else
            LED = 0; // turn OFF led
        RCIF = 0;
    }
}
```

Depending on your logic, the `else` might be placed after the end of the outer `if` block.

Comment: Tried this, but the problems is that if(RCIF){...} is executed everytime there's data to be read, when i unpress the button '1' the led remains ON because the if(RCIF) isn't executed anymore. Also if i put the else on the outer if(RCIF) it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Don't you get a button-released event via UART?

Comment: @Gerhardh That would be a GPIO interrupt not UART. Considering that he's checking an interrupt flag specifically for the UART module, the button release in only seems to cease the sending off data and its unclear to me whether or not he gets an interrupt when the `RCIF` bit is cleared.

Answer (score 1):

The LED goes off quickly after receiving any character. 
RCIF flag will only set if UART data is received. So to turn off the LED you should start a timer of certain millisec and unless your reception is completed keep on restarting the timer.

````
void __interrupt () ISR (void)
{   
    if(RCIF) // data is received
    {
        data = RCREG; // get the value
        if (data == '1') // if value received is '1'
            LED = 1; //turn ON led
        RCIF = 0;
        start_timer_interrupt(x_ms);  //set x_ms optimum timing so as to LED ON is visable with UART Rx
        flag_rx_timer=1;
    }

    if(TIMER_OVERFLOW) //TIMER_OVERFLOW is an example keyword used here. Pleas add exact timer overflow flag
    {
        if(flag_rx_timer)  //check if timer overflow is because of timer started during UART Rx
        {
             LED = 0;
             flag_rx_timer=0;
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Could you please specify what start_timer_interrupt(x_ms); means? is that a delay using timers?

Comment: You need to study how timer should be implemented in PIC. Refer the link- http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/51682a.pdf

Comment: @NitinJadhav If you wanted to have a timer turn on and off an LED, it should have its own interrupt that handles the overflow. No one who actually does real firmware development would tie the two together.